# Migrating from parse to aws sns

Tags: parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I am doing this activity following this tutorial.

https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3NE69QDHI7LJK/Migrating-from-Parse-Push-to-Amazon-SNS

When i am reach or run step 4, it's given an error.

Verify platform application: app/APNS/FILENAME

could not create all topics
Program has end

Why this error is showing, anyone can help.

Comment: did you ever find out what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out the problem. Some items in my JSON didn't have the "channels" key/value, and it failed. By removing the entries without the channels key the import was successful.

Hope it helps someone else